# How to rollback to previous version of Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, rollback

I updated by Gitlab recently, but by backup file is in older version which will be incompatible for new version. So I want to rollback the Gitlab to previous version. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitLab upgrade process is supposed to upgrade the database (and the other files should be compatible).

But anyway, if you want to downgrade, try from a fresh installation of the older GitLab, and add your files in it, reimport your database backup.

See "[Restoring from backup after a failed upgrade](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/update/restore_after_failure.html) " (based on [older GitLab archives](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/archives/), and your database backup) for the full process.

Comment: I think fresh installation will install updated version only. Then why is the use of reinstall??

Comment: @RajanaDeepak A fresh installation can be done from any past release of GitLab (https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/archives/)

Comment: So there is no rollback option in Gitlab?

Comment: @RajanaDeepak Not "option" but "process": I have added the link in the answer.